# move jCombobox button to the left

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a jCombobox and i want to move the button used to display the choices to the left. Any idea of how to do this?

```
---------------------------
|\/ |Combobox             |
--------------------------
```

thanks

Comment: why? Standard components are ... well ... standard :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could call this on the JComboBox:

```
jComboBox.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

That should set the button to the left side. It will not, however, change the alignment of the elements in the drop-down-list.

Comment: Thanks, i already had a DefaultListCellRenderer so it took care of the text.